# Divs in Twitter Bootstrap Carousel appear on top of each other

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have an issue with my Twitter Bootstrat Carousel. The 4 DIV elements which are supposed to appear one after the other all appear together, on top of each other.

I followed CreativityTuts.org tutorial and cannot see where I am wrong...

Here is the HTML code:

```
<html>


<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('.carousel').carousel({
                interval:2000
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6 well">
                <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <center>
                        <div class="item active"><img src="bkk.png"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="brr.png"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="buu.png"></div>
                        <div class="item"><img src="btt.png"></div>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

My file structure is the following:

```
- bkk.png (and the 3 other images)
- css (file)
- fonts (file)
- js (file)
    - carousel.js
    - bootstrap.js
    - bootstrap.min.js
- testcarousel.html
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Paul

Comment: is this bootstrap 2 or 3? You have a span6 which would indicate bootstrap 2

Comment: You should A) use Bootstrap 3 ([here](http://getbootstrap.com/)) and B) only include **bootstrap.min.js** and get rid off the other two JS files.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys,
Thanks for your answers, it made me realize that I used code for Bootstrap 2, but actually using Bootstrap 3.

I found needed syntax here:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php